# Erro ao abrir aplicação em Delphi no Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard x64

Tags: windows, delphi-10

Application Error
Exception EIBNativeException in module Autosad.exe at 003AF7F1.
[FireDAC][Phys][FB]Unable to complete network request to host "PROSYSTEM-01".
Failed to locate host machine.
The specified name was not found in the hosts file or Domain Name Services.

```
Assinatura do problema:
Nome do Evento de Problema: APPCRASH
Nome do Aplicativo: Autosad.exe
Versão do Aplicativo:   5.0.1.12
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Aplicativo: 59ce2b51
Nome do Módulo de Falhas:   KERNELBASE.dll
Versão do Módulo de Falhas: 6.1.7601.23807
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Módulo de Falhas:   5915f98e
Código de Exceção:  0eedfade
Deslocamento de Exceção:    0000c54f
Versão do sistema operacional:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
Identificação da Localidade:    1046
Informações Adicionais 1:   f2cc
Informações Adicionais 2:   f2ccbc68d112ff187876a3f79cd3a775
Informações Adicionais 3:   5c0f
Informações Adicionais 4:   5c0f0cc2cf2b519ef5f16835eedb4819
```

Essa mensagem aparece logo apos tentar abrir o sistema 
sistema criado em Delphi 10.1 
vi uma Solução em "Prevenção de Execução de Dados" e não Funcionou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre Quando o banco de dados não é encontrado. verifique a rota da base de dados.